# In Solana, how do I know if an Account is modified in a given transaction?

Tags: blockchain, solana

I know there's an API called `accountSubscribe` that I can use to get notified when an Account is modified when new blocks arrive. But for historical blocks / transactions, how can I tell if an Account was modified by a given transaction?

I define "modified" as data or lamport changes, instead of being just read-only accessed. Just like in WebSocket subscriptions, if such a change happens in transactions, it should be spotted out.

I noticed that in the `getTransaction` API, the returned structure has `transaction.message.accountKeys` where each item has a field `writable`. I wonder if it's safe to say, if `meta.err` of the transaction is `null` and the `writable` field is `true`, the Account is modified by that transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using the normal RPC endpoints, there's no way to be sure.

If a transaction succeeded and the account was writable, the account data could have stayed the same. For example, if I transfer 0 tokens to you, the transaction will succeed, and be shown as "writable", but no modification was done.

If you only care about SOL / token balances, you can use the `preTokenBalances` vs `postTokenBalances` or `preBalances` vs `postBalances` when fetching past transactions. More info at https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction

Past that, there's no way to know currently.

Comment: If such a 0-token transfer takes place between two accounts, will the two accounts appear in a generated `AccountNotification` if I subscribe to it via WebSocket `accountSubscribe`? What I'd like to know about is if I can have information sufficient enough from HTTP JSON-RPC responses to replicate the behaviors of some WebSocket method `accountSubscribe`.

Comment: Not for SPL tokens or SOL wallets, no.